# AWS AMI Bitnami + Webmin can't access over https://publicip:10000

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04, webmin, virtualmin

I'm using an AWS AMI from Bitnami "[NGinx Certified by Bitnami](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00NPHKI3Y)" and I have installed Webmin successfully as seen in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/s3w47m88/81dc5f76a2e89b9b1864399c72c9ed79). Including opening the port 10000 in the firewall. But I still cannot access WebMin at https://publicip:10000 - it just times out. I've rebuilt the server twice and tried with another Bitnami image but get the same result.

I've installed Webmin on other servers many times successfully. Although it's been a couple years.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered I had to allow the port in Amazon's AWS interface.

1. Sign into the Amazon AWS
2. Console.
3. Select EC2.
4. Navigate to "Network & Security" > "Security Groups".
5. Select the Security Group you previously associated with your instance.
6. In the panel that appears / populates below select "Inbound"
7. Click the "Edit" button.
8. Click "Add Rule"
9. Choose "Custom TPC"
10. Enter "TCP" as the Protocol.
11. Enter "10000" as the port range.
12. Select "Custom" as the Source and enter "0.0.0.0/0" as the value.
13. (Optional) Enter "Webmin" as the Description.
14. Click and click save.